# Subtheme update

Tags: theming, updating

An update has become available for a given theme (Bootstrap Barrio). I had configured the previous release into a subtheme. How can I update the subtheme, or at least make a new subtheme of the updated one, and be sure that no modification performed in the old subtheme get lost?

Comment: I would follow the theme’s upgrade guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/themes/barrio-bootstrap-4-drupal-89-theme/bootstrap-barrio-installation/upgrade-barrio-from-8x-4x-to-5x-version#s-barrio-5x-upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have made all the adjustments in the subtheme, I understand that there will be problems, because what will be updated is the parent theme.

Just confirm that the subtheme in the info.yml file has at least this:

bootstrap_barrio_subtheme.info.yml

```
name: Bootstrap Barrio Subtheme
type: theme
description: 'Basic structure for a Bootstrap Barrio SubTheme.'
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9 || ^10
base theme: bootstrap_barrio
```

Comment: Yes: `name` etc and, in particular, `base theme` are unvaried. But `version` still reads 5.5.6, rather than 5.5.16. The latter information was added automatically bu drupal packaging script at the time when the subtheme was created. Do I get it correctly, that the subtheme inherits all updates of the base theme and that, therefore, I shouldn't possibly worry much, provided my changes to the subtheme were mainly in style (choice of colors, regions to be activated, etc)?

Comment: That's right. If all your functionality is in the subtheme, everything will be fine. The problem would be if all your functionality was in the parent theme, because if it were updated, you could lose functionality. Greetings and God bless you.